# Opening Excel file Using ClosedXML Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, closedxml

I am trying to open a 6MB Excel file in ASP.NET using ClosedXML but I am getting an error saying *"Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object."*

Here's my code:

```
    Dim temppath = Path.GetTempPath()
    Dim filenamestr As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName())

    Dim tempfilename As String = Path.Combine(temppath, filenamestr + ".xlsx")
    Using fs = New FileStream(tempfilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        xlStream.WriteTo(fs)
    End Using

    Dim xlwb = New XLWorkbook(tempfilename) 'The part having the error
```

Source: "DocumentFormat.OpenXml"
I also tried opening an existing Excel file, it still results to this error. Also tried putting the file in different directories thinking it's just because of the permission of my drives, no luck at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the real time working code used to get excel file in closed xml

```
 private void workbookProcessing(string workbookname)
    {
        SqlDatabase objdb = new SqlDatabase ( OSMC.constring_Property );
```

//Below the boqserverfilepath refers the folder where excel files stored EX: "~/Uploaded_Boq/";

```
        string fullfilename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ( OneStopMethods_Common.boqserverfilepath + workbookname );
        XLWorkbook theWorkBook = new XLWorkbook ( fullfilename );
        int worksheetcount = theWorkBook.Worksheets.Count;
        foreach(IXLWorksheet theWorkSheet in theWorkBook.Worksheets)
        {
            foreach(IXLRow therow in theWorkSheet.Rows())
            {
                foreach(IXLCell thecell in therow.Cells())
                {
                                        int tenderid = 1001;

                                        int  Activity_Section_objseq = tenderosm.generateNextTenderObjSequenceNo ( tenderid, "tender_boq_activity_section" );
                                        string boqactivitysectionInsquery = " insert into tender_boq_activity_section(fk_tender_id,obj_seq_no,parent_obj_seq_no,activity_section_no,workbook_name,worksheet_name,row_index,cell_reference,element_type,element_description) values(" + tenderid + "," + Activity_Section_objseq + ",' 10 ','20','" + workbookname + "','" + theWorkSheet.Name + "'," + therow.RowNumber ( ) + ",'"+thecell.Address+"','activity','" + thecell.Value + "');";
                                        objdb.ExecuteNonQuery ( CommandType.Text, boqactivitysectionInsquery );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You take the values as per your requirement and insert the values in the database.

Hope the above information will be useful. Kindly let me know your thoughts.

thanks
karthik